# Adding an "all" option to my HTML select tag

Tags: php, html, sql

So I'm on my way to completing my website. However I was wondering, how can I structure my SQL statement so when I click the submit button with an option having "all" I get all the results in that field with the addition of the other criteria. If you know any good tutorials could you please recommend one.

```
<select name="make" id ="make" size="0">
    <option selected ="all">All</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
    <option value="honda">Honda</option>
    <option value ="nissan">Nissan</option>
    <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM  `chjadb_vehicles` WHERE  `v_make` LIKE '$make');
```

Comment: The best method is to build your where clause as a string, including the parts that aren't set to "ALL", then apend that to the end of your SELECT.

Comment: And if you have that much control of the sql string then just omit that filter condition (or the entire `WHERE` clause even.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that only requires changing the SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM chjadb_vehicles
WHERE (v_make = '$make' OR '$make' = 'all')
```

The parentheses are not strictly necessary here but I added them anyway in case you later decide to add another `AND ...` condition.

Comment: When i modify that line of code and run it the result turns up blank

Comment: @DarienRuddock: Are you sure that the value of `$make` is set? Can you post the SQL you get after variable interpolation (i.e. the contents of the `$sql` variable)? Can you show what data you have in your database? Can you post the code you use to display the results?

Comment: @MarkByers Isn't the html option element missing the value attribute for 'All'?

Comment: No "all" should select all items in that column... should be something to this effect...  WHERE `v_make` LIKE 'nissan OR `v_make` = honda' i want to fit it in here <option value = "nissan OR `v_make` = honda">All</option>

Comment: Yes, and to make that happen you need a predicate that becomes `OR 'all' = 'all'`. And to make that happen it needs to get a value from the make selection. So the option element needs to have `value='all'` that gets interpolated for the query. You don't have that because the html is wrong.

Comment: I just realized what you meant in your last comment. You don't need to start placing snippets of sql in your html. Let the query handle the logic. The road you're going down has all sorts of sql injection perils.

Comment: Wow so true but i'm not sure how to approach this, as i was following tutorials online and that how they suggested i do it. Where can i go to access a method that's more secure?

Comment: I don't really know php but I assume there's a concept of parameterized queries. If nothing else, you could make it a little safer by removing single quote characters and hyphens before dropping it into the query.

Comment: How to make it secure depends on which API you are using. Since you have shown absolutely zero DB access code it's rather hard to advise, but assuming you are using the old and obsolete mysql API then you can use `mysql_real_escape_string`. All this is described in the manual.

Comment: Yes im using mysql_real_escape_string but i need more security than that... I'll have to take another look at the code. Do you guys know any good books i could purchase?